# A Persisted Spark DataFrame is computed twice

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, persist

I have some PySpark code like below. Basically, I persist a DataFrame (which is time-consuming to compute) to disk, call the method `DataFrame.count` to trigger the caching/persist immediately, and then I coalesce the DataFrame to reduce the number of partitions (the original DataFrame has 30,000 partitions) and output it to HDFS. Based on the execution time of job stages and the execution plan, it seems to me that the DataFrame is recomputed at `df.coalesce(300)`. Does anyone know why this happens? Is it because `coalesce` is optimized to have different lineage than the cache DataFrame so that Spark doesn't know the cache version can be used?

```
df = spark.read.parquet("/input/hdfs/path") \
    .filter(...) \
    .withColumn("new_col", my_pandas_udf("col0", "col1")) \
    .persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
df.count()
df.coalesce(300).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(output_mod)
```

BTW, it works well if I manually write the DataFrame to HDFS, read it back, coalesce it and write it back to HDFS.